# Send data contained in the programmatically(through JSON) created ListView to the same Activity on each click

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent

**Not solved yet, so someone please help. Please.**

I have a ListView in Main Activity which is being populated dynamically by the data from Google Books API JSON and I want to start a new Intent(same activity every time) on the click on ListView so that it carries with it all the data contained in the clicked ListView item. I'm using "Bundle" but unable to do that.
See the details below and please tell me what mistake I'm making. I'm a newbie and completely stuck on it for 2-3 days.
 Kindly see and help me. Thanks.
**My problem is similar to the following questions but the solution there couldn't help me. These are the links to those threads: [how to start new activity in listview item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395060/how-to-start-new-activity-in-listview-item-click) and [Pass custom list item content to new activity when list item is clicked from a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387301/pass-custom-list-item-content-to-new-activity-when-list-item-is-clicked-from-a-l)**

Here is my **MainActivity:** which populate the activity_main.xml with "title, author, and publisher very easliy"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String title;
String firstAuthor;
String publisher;
String pageCount;
String description;
int averageRating;
String publishedDate;
String isbnType;
String isbnValue;
Books booksObject = new Books();

private String searchQuery;
/**
 * Tag for the log messages
 */
public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
/**
 * URL to query the GoogleBook dataset for book's information
 */
private static String BOOK_REQUEST_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Find the edit text's actual text and make it compatible for a url search query
            searchQuery = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchQuery)).getText().toString().replace(" ", "+");
            //Check if user input is empty or it contains some query text
            if (searchQuery.isEmpty()) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String text = "Nothing Entered in Search";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                // String to be attached to the BOOK_REQUEST_URL
                String appendableQuery = searchQuery + "&key=MyGoogleBookAPIKey&maxResults=10&country=IN";
                BOOK_REQUEST_URL += appendableQuery; //final value of "URL for Google Book API"
                BookAsyncTask task = new BookAsyncTask();
                //If network is available then perform the further task of AsynckTask calling
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    // Kick off an {@link AsyncTask} to perform the network request
                    task.execute();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Reset the to the original URL to prevent app crash
                    BOOK_REQUEST_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

//Check if network is available or not
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

/**
 * Update the screen to display information from the given {@link Books}.
 */
private void updateUi(final ArrayList<Books> book) {
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    BooksAdapter booksAdapter = new BooksAdapter(MainActivity.this, book);
    listView.setAdapter(booksAdapter);

            /*Setting click listener on ListView*/
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Books bookses = book.get(position);
            Bundle bookDetailsBundle = new Bundle();
            bookDetailsBundle.putParcelableArrayList("bookDetailsArrayList", book);
            Intent booksIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookDetailsActivity.class);
            booksIntent.putExtra("bookDetailsBundle", bookDetailsBundle);
            startActivity(booksIntent);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * {@link AsyncTask} to perform the network request on a background thread, and then
 * update the UI with the first earthquake in the response.
 */
private class BookAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, ArrayList<Books>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Books> doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // Create URL object
        URL url = createUrl(BOOK_REQUEST_URL);

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = "";
        try {
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle the IOException
        }

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create an {@link Books} object
        ArrayList<Books> book = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);

        // Return the {@link Books} object as the result fo the {@link BookAsyncTask}
        return book;
    }

    /**
     * Update the screen with the given book (which was the result of the
     * {@link BookAsyncTask}).
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Books> book) {
        if (book == null) {
            return;
        }
        updateUi(book);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchQuery);
        editText.setText(null);
        BOOK_REQUEST_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";  //Reset the to the original URL
    }

    /**
     * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
     */
    private URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Creating URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
     */
    private String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.connect();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Response Code: "
                        + urlConnection.getResponseCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the exception
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is an IO exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // function must handle java.io.IOException here
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
     * whole JSON response from the server.
     */
    private String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Return an {@link Books} object by parsing out information
     * about the first earthquake from the input googleBooksJSON string.
     */
    private ArrayList<Books> extractFeatureFromJson(String googleBooksJSON) {
        try {
            ArrayList<Books> arrayListOfBooks = new ArrayList<Books>();
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(googleBooksJSON);
            //Check if the base/root JSONObject has the desired "key" of value "items" and then only proceed
            if (baseJsonResponse.has("items")) {
                JSONArray itemsArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");
                if (itemsArray.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject volumeInfo = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                        //Check if the JSONObject volumeInfo has the desired string with value "title" and then only proceed
                        booksObject.setVolumeId(i);
                        if (volumeInfo.has("title")) {
                            title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                            booksObject.setTitle(title);
                        }
                        // String publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");
                        //Check if the JSONObject volumeInfo has the desired string with value "authors" and then only proceed
                        if (volumeInfo.has("authors")) {
                            JSONArray authors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                            //get first author's name
                            firstAuthor = authors.getString(0);
                            booksObject.setAuthor(firstAuthor);
                        }
                        if (volumeInfo.has("publisher")) {
                            publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");
                            booksObject.setPublisher(publisher);
                        }
                        if (volumeInfo.has("pageCount")) {
                            pageCount = volumeInfo.getString("pageCount");
                            booksObject.setPageCount(pageCount);
                        }
                        if (volumeInfo.has("description")) {
                            description = volumeInfo.getString("description");
                            booksObject.setDescription(description);
                        }
                        if (volumeInfo.has("averageRating")) {
                            averageRating = volumeInfo.getInt("averageRating");
                            booksObject.setRatings(averageRating);
                        }
                        if (volumeInfo.has("publishedDate")) {
                            publishedDate = volumeInfo.getString("publishedDate");
                            booksObject.setPublishedDate(publishedDate);
                        }
                        if (volumeInfo.has("industryIdentifiers")) {
                            JSONArray industryIdentifiers = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("industryIdentifiers");
                            JSONObject firstISBN = industryIdentifiers.getJSONObject(0);
                            isbnType = firstISBN.getString("type");
                            isbnValue = firstISBN.getString("identifier");
                            booksObject.setISBNType(isbnType);
                            booksObject.setISBNValue(isbnValue);
                        }
                        arrayListOfBooks.add(new Books(booksObject.getVolumeId(), booksObject.getTitle(), booksObject.getAuthor(), booksObject.getPublisher(),
                                booksObject.getPageCount(), booksObject.getDescription(), booksObject.getRatings(),
                                booksObject.getPublishedDate(), booksObject.getISBNType(), booksObject.getISBNValue()));
                    }
                }
                return arrayListOfBooks;
            } else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Book found, search again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem parsing the Google Books JSON results" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}
My **BookAdapter** goes here:

```
public class BooksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView author;
    TextView publisher;
}

public BooksAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Books> books){
    super(context, 0, books);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    final Books currentBook = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        // If there's no view to re-use, inflate a brand new view for row
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_items, parent, false);
                    /*Find the TextView and ImageView and set them on the VIewHolder*/
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        viewHolder.publisher = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);



        // Cache the viewHolder object inside the fresh view
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // View is being recycled, retrieve the viewHolder object from tag
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.title.setText(currentBook.getTitle());
    viewHolder.author.setText(currentBook.getAuthor());
    viewHolder.publisher.setText(currentBook.getPublisher());
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Here is the activity(intent) which gets called every time the listview is clicked:

```
public class BookDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.book_details_listview);
    //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ArrayList<Books> booksArrayList = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bookDetailsBundle").getParcelableArrayList("bookDetailsArrayList");
    BookDetailsAdapter bookDetailsAdapter = new BookDetailsAdapter(this, booksArrayList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.book_details_listview);
    listView.setAdapter(bookDetailsAdapter);
}
```

}
**And it's Adapter is here:**

```
public class BookDetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {


public BookDetailsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Books> bookses) {
     super(context, 0, bookses);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.book_details_items, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
    Books currentBook = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
    TextView title_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title_book);
    TextView author_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.author_book);
    TextView publisher_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher_book);
    TextView page_count_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.page_count_book);
    TextView description_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description_book);
    TextView ratings_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.ratings_book);
    TextView publication_date_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.publication_date_book);
    TextView isbn_type_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.isbn_type_book);
    TextView isbn_value_book = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.isbn_value_book);

         // set this text on these TextViews
    title_book.setText(currentBook.getTitle());
    author_book.setText(currentBook.getAuthor());
    publisher_book.setText(currentBook.getPublisher());
    page_count_book.setText(currentBook.getPageCount());
    description_book.setText(currentBook.getDescription());
    ratings_book.setText(currentBook.getRatings());
    publication_date_book.setText(currentBook.getPublishedDate());
    isbn_type_book.setText(currentBook.getISBNType());
    isbn_value_book.setText(currentBook.getISBNValue());

    return listItemView;
}
```

}

Whatever I do, I get this same error:**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.android.booklisting.BookDetailsActivity.onCreate(BookDetailsActivity.java:24)**
I'm completely clueless now and lost **but know it clearly that I'm unable to get the position of the clicked "list item" of "listview" even though I tried using things like "Books books= getItem(position);" in "onItemClick".** Please tell me where exactly am I wrong and what's the solution. Your reply is most welcome.
My book_details_item is here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/book_details_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/author_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/publisher_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/page_count_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ratings_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/publication_date_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/isbn_type_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/isbn_value_book"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="book's title" />
```

Comment: I think listview is null check listview id in xml

Comment: are still getting nullpointer exception ?

Comment: post the new stack trace, after fixing the null listview issue

Comment: As per `android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132)
 at com.example.android.booklisting.BookDetailsAdapter.getView(BookDetailsAdapter.java:52)`,  you are setting null value to your TextView. Please check value before set on any TextView.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand what you said. pls check my book_details_item.xml above.